# SQL queries returning incorrect results during High Load

Tags: sql, caching, ignite

I have a table in which during the performance runs, there are inserts happening in the beginning when the job starts, during the insertion time there are also parallel operations(GET/UPDATE queries) happening on that table. The Get operation also updates a value in column marking that record as picked. However, the next get performed on the table would again return back the same record even when the record was marked in progress.

P.S. --> both the operations are done by the same single thread existing in the system. Logs below for reference, record marked in progress at Line 1 on **20:36:42,864**, however, it is returned back in the result set of query executed after **20:36:42,891** by the same thread. 
We also observed that during high load (usually during same scenario as mentioned above) some update operation (intermittent) were not happening on the table even when the update executed successfully (validated using the returned result and then doing a get just after that to check the updated value ) without throwing an exception.

13 Apr 2020 20:36:42,864 [SHT-4083-initial] FINEST  - AbstractCacheHelper.markContactInProgress:2321 -  Action state after mark in progresss contactId.ATTR=: 514409 for jobId : 4083 is actionState : 128

13 Apr 2020 20:36:42,891 [SHT-4083-initial] FINEST  - CacheAdvListMgmtHelper.getNextContactToProcess:347 - Query : select priority, contact_id, action_state, pim_contact_store_id, action_id
, retry_session_id, attempt_type, zone_id, action_pos  from pim_4083 where handler_id = ? and attempt_type != ?  and next_attempt_after <= ? and action_state = ? and exclude_flag = ?  order
by attempt_type desc, priority desc, next_attempt_after asc,contact_id asc    limit 1

This happens usually during the performance runs when there are parallel JOB's started which are working on Ignite. Can anyone suggest what can be done to avoid such a situation..?

We have 2 ignite data nodes that are deployed as springBootService deployed in the cluster being accessed, by 3 client nodes. 
Ignite version -> 2.7.6, Cache configuration is as follows,

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
   CacheConfiguration cachecfg = new CacheConfiguration(CACHE_NAME);
   cachecfg.setRebalanceThrottle(100);
   cachecfg.setBackups(1);
   cachecfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
   cachecfg.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.ASYNC);
   cachecfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
   cachecfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
   // Defining and creating a new cache to be used by Ignite Spring Data repository.
   CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration(CACHE_TEMPLATE);
   ccfg.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
   ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);
   ccfg.setBackups(1);
       DataStorageConfiguration dsCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
           dsCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
           dsCfg.setStoragePath(storagePath);
           dsCfg.setWalMode(WALMode.FSYNC);
           dsCfg.setWalPath(walStoragePath);
           dsCfg.setWalArchivePath(archiveWalStoragePath);
           dsCfg.setWriteThrottlingEnabled(true);
           cfg.setAuthenticationEnabled(true);
       dsCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration()
            .setInitialSize(Long.parseLong(cacheInitialMemSize) * 1024 * 1024);
       dsCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setMaxSize(Long.parseLong(cacheMaxMemSize) * 1024 * 1024);
       cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(dsCfg);

   cfg.setClientConnectorConfiguration(clientCfg);
   // Run the command to alter the default user credentials
   // ALTER USER "ignite" WITH PASSWORD 'new_passwd'
   cfg.setCacheConfiguration(cachecfg);
   cfg.setFailureDetectionTimeout(Long.parseLong(cacheFailureTimeout));
   ccfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
   ccfg.setWriteSynchronizationMode(CacheWriteSynchronizationMode.FULL_SYNC);
   ccfg.setRebalanceMode(CacheRebalanceMode.ASYNC);
   ccfg.setRebalanceThrottle(100);
   int pool = cfg.getSystemThreadPoolSize();
       cfg.setRebalanceThreadPoolSize(2);
   cfg.setLifecycleBeans(new MyLifecycleBean());
   logger.info(methodName, "Starting ignite service");
   ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
   ignite.cluster().active(true);
   // Get all server nodes that are already up and running.
   Collection<ClusterNode> nodes = ignite.cluster().forServers().nodes();
   // Set the baseline topology that is represented by these nodes.
   ignite.cluster().setBaselineTopology(nodes);
   ignite.addCacheConfiguration(ccfg);
```

Comment: The same SQL query executed against the same data should always return the same result set, period.  It sounds here like you have interleaving operations which are updating/changing your data.

Comment: validated the same, there are no operations changing/updating data in between, and this happens intermittently when parallel jobs are started.

Comment: Are you sure that next Get request happens strictly after first one is complete, or it just happens to finish after the first one?

Comment: yes, its the same single thread, that is making the call to DB and works in the loop..

Comment: "The Get operation also updates a value in column marking that record as picked" could you please explain, what do you mean here? How do you distinguish the rows? And what is the modification logic for GET operation?

Comment: @Alexandr -- basically there are two operations happening when a call to get a new record is made, first there is a query executed on the cache that returns a row, next the same row is updated with a column that marks that this row/record is picked for processing.Only when both the operations are complete (both queries executed) the flow returns back to the calling code.